# comments url helper - using rails - LinkBot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-rewriting, urlhelper

K... This seems pretty straight forward, but it's not standardized, it would seem.  I've only been looking for a few hours, but hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

So, an instance of an `Object` has a description.  `Object has_many comments`.  If a user posts a URL in one of those fields, http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ree-drummond/tequila-lime-chicken-recipe/index.html , for instance.  As I'm typing this, I see below that somehow, something knew to convert that to a clickable link.  I'd like to take that a step further.  I'd like to see that same link transformed into just the main url, but still the actual link, a la [foodnetwork](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ree-drummond/tequila-lime-chicken-recipe/index.html).

Can rails do something like that on the fly?  Is there a gem for something like that?  Should I set out to make aforementioned link_bot gem?

After some pointers in the right direction, I went with a helper method, as playing in the model wasn't working.  View:

```
<% if object.comments.any? %>
  <% object.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div class='comment block'>
      <div class='comment user'>
        <%= first_name(comment.user) %>
        <span class='comment time'><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</span>
      </div>
      <div class='comment content'>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<%= parse_links(comment.content) %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In a helper:

```
def parse_links(comment)
  auto_link(comment, html: {target: '_blank'}) do |text|
    URI.parse(text).host
  end
end
```

Cheers!

Comment: Try my updated answer, I haven't used `auto_links` before so not sure if it will work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the [auto_link gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink).

They give an example of playing around with the link text:

```
post_body = "Welcome to my new blog at http://www.myblog.com/.  Please e-mail me at me@email.com."
auto_link(post_body, :html => { :target => '_blank' }) do |text|
  truncate(text, 15)
end
# => "Welcome to my new blog at <a href=\"http://www.myblog.com/\" target=\"_blank\">http://www.m...</a>.
```

#### Update

Try this:

```
<%= auto_link(comment.content, html: {target: '_blank'}) do |text| %>
   # if URI.parse(text).host doesn't work try a regex:
   <%= text.match(/http:\/\/([^\/]*).*/)[1] %> # is there a better way to do this regex?
   # also try just <% instead of <%= if you get weird outputs.
<% end %>
```

If you get any errors add them to your question.

Comment: I think OP is talking about some JavaScript feature, turning url text into link on the fly when typing, just like we input url in SO comment or answer.

Comment: negatory.  I was just noticing the capability as I typed.  This would be info from a model.  I have no idea how it works, but that is what I want.  do I do this in the view or the controller??  updated original with what I'm trying...

Comment: `undefined method 'auto_link' for #<Comment:0x23408e8>` - I read in some other places about this being a view helper and not playing nicely?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought might happen... I'm not sure if you can use  `URI` in the views either. Try a regex instead, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: i tried it in a helper as `parse_links(comment)` and i get a bit farther, i think.  `undefined method 'empty?' for #<Comment:0x23b63f8>` but i don't see any use of `.empty?` anywhere.

Comment: check it.  actually put this in a helper method and it worked.  was getting the previous error because i was using `parse_links(comment)`. derp.  changed that to `parse_links(comment.content)` and it works like a charm! (with the URI in the helper)  thanks!